# How do I get cumulative sum based on 'if' condition using a Boolean variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sumifs

I have the following data frame:

```
vote_prprtn uniform_votesh  p_by_q    ln_p_by_q   p_ln_p_by_q   match
0.0116     0.009367        1.238434   0.213848   0.002481       False
0.0100     0.009367        1.067616   0.065428   0.000654       True
0.0065     0.009367        0.693950  -0.365355   -0.002375      True
0.0072     0.006000        1.200000   0.182321   0.001313       False
0.0048     0.006000        0.800000  -0.223143   -0.001071      True
```

I want to create another column which has the row value of p_ln_p_by_q when match = False and does a cumulative sum, row by row when match is True. This continues until the next False value. My final dataframe should look like this:

```
vote_prprtn uniform_votesh  p_by_q    ln_p_by_q   p_ln_p_by_q   match   final_val
0.0116     0.009367        1.238434   0.213848   0.002481       False    0.002481
0.0100     0.009367        1.067616   0.065428   0.000654       True     0.003135
0.0065     0.009367        0.693950  -0.365355   -0.002375      True     0.00076
0.0072     0.006000        1.200000   0.182321   0.001313       False    0.001313 
0.0048     0.006000        0.800000  -0.223143   -0.001071      True     0.000242
```

Any help on this would genuinely make me understand the parallels between excel and pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) using a group defined by each time `match==False` then do the [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) over each group.

```
df['final_val'] = df.groupby((~df.match).cumsum())['p_ln_p_by_q'].cumsum()

df['final_val']
# 0 0.002481
# 1 0.003135
# 2 0.000760
# 3 0.001313
# 4 0.000242
```

Comment: your code works perfectly. I googled ```cumsum()``` and learnt that it is a function to get the cumulative sum. I understand that you are trying to group by the False values in match column and want to do a cumulative sum on those grouped values. But I wonder why you have used ```cumsum()``` in ```((~df.match).cumsum())```. Can you please explain this?

Comment: Sure, the first five records of `match` are `[False, True, True, False, True]` Where the first three records belongs to group `1` while the last 2 belongs to group `2`, negating `match` the result is `[True, False, False, True, False]` and if you do a `cumsum()` then: `[1,1,1, 2,2]` because as integers `True == 1` and `False ==0`  so basically you have created a column to tell the groupby which are the groups.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your data frame is done, but you can try something in this style :

```
sum = 0
for row in frame.rows:
 if(row.match == False):
  sum = 0
 sum += row.p_ln_p_by_q
 row.final_val = sum
```

(Take care to adapt the way you read/write in your row, this is just a Python-based pseudo-code).